# Difference between pointer and array syntax

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, posix

I'm very new to C and I'm figuring out the syntax a little bit. But I'm confused as to the following differences. If somebody could explain their differences and what that means for how I can manipulate them. Thanks

```
 char  *word 
 char **word 
 char  array[] 
 char *array[]
```

Comment: You should go through a basic tutorial.

Comment: Read [K&R](http://books.cat-v.org/computer-science/c-programming-language/The.C.Programming.Language.2nd.Edition.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

```
char  *word      //pointer to char
char **word      //pointer to a pointer to a char
char  array[]    //array of char of undefined size
char *array[]    //array of pointers to char of undefined size
```

Now all you have to do is to read a book about pointers to "figuring out the syntax a little bit".

Comment: What do you mean by "undefined size"?

Comment: "Undefined size" means that you have not given it a size, which is specified inside of the brackets. *Ex:*
`char word[128]` <-- that allocates a 128-element-array of `char`.

Comment: what about char **array[] ?

Comment: You really should read some beginners book. It´s an array of pointers to pointers to chars, with undefined size. But if you don´t understand the whole concept of pointers etc., this won´t help you.

Answer (score 1):

C declarations are based on the types of *expressions*, not objects.

For example, suppose you have a pointer to an integer named `p`, and you want to access the value that `p` points to.  You'd use the dereference operator `*` like so:

```
x = *p;
```

The *expression* `*p` yields a value of type `int`, so the declaration is written as

```
int *p; // which is parsed as int (*p); the * is bound to the identifier p,
        // not the type specifier
```

For a slightly more complicated example, you have an array of pointers to `char`, and you want to access the pointed-to character.  You'd index into the array and dereference the result:

```
c = *a[i]; // which is parsed as `*(a[i])`
```

Again, the type of the *expression* `*a[i]` is `char`, so the declaration of `a` is written

```
char *a[N];
```

So, going through the specific examples:

```
char  *word;   // word is a pointer to char
char **word;   // word is a pointer to a pointer to char
char array[];  // array is an array of char 
char *array[]; // array is an array of pointers to char
```

Note that an array declaration *must* include a size or have an initializer; your array declarations
are not correct.

The array subscript operator `[]` and function call `()` have higher precedence than unary `*`, so:

```
T *a[N];     // a is an N-element array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N];   // a is a pointer to an N-element array of T
T *f();      // f is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*f)();    // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```